# Как узнать что клавиша нажата при выделении? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при выделении чего-либо на странице срабатывала функция при нажатии клавиши, но в консоли ничего не выводит. Почему?

```
$(document).select(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 16) {
    console.log("You are pressing 'Shift' ");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 16) {
    console.log("You are pressing Shift")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *Хочу сделать так, чтобы при выделении чего-либо на странице срабатывала функция при нажатии клавиши* - видимо, автору надо еще и событие выделения

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @AndrewSE это можно сделать несколькими способами. Один из вариантов: слушаете события `select` и если оно произошло, то ставите слушатель на `keydown`, `keyup`, etc. После того как произойдет deselect (`blur`, etc.) убираете слушатель с `keydown`